# How to convert web.config. to .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-config

I need to turn a **web.config** file into a **.htaccess** file
I have this **web.config** (`pastebin.com/rQPMMC2m`)

How can I turn it into a **.htaccess** file?

Is there any method to do an automatic conversion?
Thank you!

Comment: Formatting done in review.

Comment: Please post the content of the file _inline_ in the question. Links to off-site resources are not accepted as a replacement. That is clearly explained in the section "how to ask". There is an `edit` link below the question, please use it to revise your question.